# How can I test the grant type authorization code for oauth2 on WSO2?

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, identity, wso2-identity-server

Found samples for Custom grant, password and credentials. Is there some sample (nodejs, curl, java or any other option) that you can test the authorization code with the playground2?

- Oauth with Grant Type Password:
  http://xacmlinfo.org/2015/03/09/openid-connect-support-with-resource-owner-password-grant-type/
- Oauth with Grant Type Credentials:
  http://xacmlinfo.org/2013/12/02/client-credential-grant-type-with-oauth-2-0/

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can try the Authorization Code grant type in the browser without having to use any web app. I wrote a blog post on how to do it [1]

You can test the authorization grant with a combination of a browser redirect and a curl command. The step by step guide with screenshots to achieving this is explained in the blog post.

Let me explain the summary of steps here,

1. Log in to Identity Server (5.1.0 or higher)
2. Create a Service Provider and enable Inbound OAuth Authentication
3. Provide the callback URL as "https://localhost/callback"
4. Open a private window in a browser and type in the below URL. Replace {client_id} with the client_id of the OAuth client_id of the Service Provider

https://localhost:9443/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri=https://localhost/callback&scope=read

5. Next, you will be prompted to login and thereafter to approve for consent.
6. You will be redirected with the authorization code as "code"
   query param in the URL
7. Use a CURL request to the token endpoint to get a valid access token

curl -k -v --user {client_id}:{client_secret} -d "grant_type=authorization_code&code={authorization_code}&redirect_uri=https://localhost/callback" https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token

(replace {client_id},{client_secret} and {authorization_code} with correct values)

You can refer [1] for screenshots.

[1] http://blog.farazath.com/2016/05/trying-out-oauth2-authorization-code.html

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: updated the answer since  I have enough reputation to post more than two links in the answer

Comment: Hi @farasath, it´s possible to do that without the use of a browser?

Answer (score 0):

You can quickly download and spin up an IS 5.0.0 and then configure it with the Info Recovery Sample.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Recovering+Account+Information+Using+a+Webapp

The sample is a simple self service account management tool.